# MySQL MAMPでインストールするものとターミナルで起動するもの

Tags: mysql

MySQL MAMPでインストールするものとターミナルで起動するものはちがいますか ？

Answer (score 0):

インストールした複数のMySQLが同じ機能を持つかそうでないかは、バージョンを比較すればわかります。バージョンが同じMySQLはインストールの方法にかかわらず同じ機能を持ちます。

MAMPの場合、[公式ドキュメント](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Servers-and-Services/MySQL/)によれば、管理画面の右上から確認できるようです。通常のMySQLであれば、`$ mysql --version`とコマンドを打てばバージョンが出力されます（ただし、`mysql` というコマンドがMAMPでインストールされたMySQLを指している場合もあります）。

参考：[MySQLのバージョン確認方法](https://qiita.com/rokumura7/items/b270acb9550efddd5fe5)